# How can elements scroll to a fixed header using Velocity.js?

Tags: scroll, velocity.js

The fixed header have different height in different resolution. I know Jquery can do this job from other stackoverflow post like this:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('.element').offset().top - $('.header').outerHeight() + 'px'
    }, 1000);
```

How can I achieve this with Velocity.js?

Answer (score 0):

Velocity's Scroll command take an offset option:

```
$element.velocity("scroll", {offset: -60 })
```